# Video Chat feature for Django and possibly Ionic

Tags: android, python, django, video, ionic-framework

I developed a website with Django (Python). This website allows users to make 1-to-1 video chat with each others.
For the video chat feature I'm currently using WebRTC with quite good results.

Now I'm planning to:

- upgrade to a paid service for video chat (to improve preformances and fix browser incompatibilities)
- ideally using the same paid service for a Ionic app (both Android and iOS) - so that service should provide Android/iOS SDKs

I'm thinking about CometChat. Do you have any experience with it or other services? Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an API for charging your users and provide us the same according to the below-mentioned steps:

1. Create a feature on your site which allows users to purchase credits (by making payment)
2. Create a simple API to deduct credits and check number of credits

Once you provide us the API, we will then modify CometChat so that when a user sends a message we can check the number of credits and deduct them using your API.

Please let  know if you need any further assistance about the same.

Regards